# joining two lists of lists by index

Tags: python

I have two list of lists of the same length, something like the following.

```
list1 = [[],[],[1,2,3,4],[],[2,5,6]]
list2 = [[],[],[1,9,3,9],[],[1,8,6]]
```

I want to join these lists so that if there are values in the list it will be added to the same index in the list, eg `[[],[],[1,2,3,4,9],[],[1,2,5,6,8]]`. 
I was trying to use `map(list,zip(list1,list2))` but that merges both lists into a list giving for example two empty lists inside `index[0]`. Instead of this I want to the values from both lists in `index[0]` added to `index[0]` and if there are no values in either list then this list should remain empty. What would be the best way to do this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not terribly far, you just need to refine what you're doing.

```
>>> [sorted(set(e1 + e2)) for (e1, e2) in zip(list1, list2)]
[[], [], [1, 2, 3, 4, 9], [], [1, 2, 5, 6, 8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to iterate over both lists and extend the lists in one of the lists.

for i in range(0, len(list1)):
 list1[i].extend(list2[i])

Then all the items in list1 would be the items in list1 and 2 including appended lists.